# Want to print the date only in blade.php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I am using laravel 7.2 .In my db column there is date and time stored together like is 2013-08-01 00:00:00 .but in blade.php I want to print the date only like 2013-08-01.here is my blade.php code

```
<td>{{$invoice->invoice_created_date}}</td>
<td>IL {{$invoice->invoice_id}}</td>
```

Comment: You can use [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/): `{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($invoice->invoice_created_date)->format('Y-m-d')}}`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `date` function to format your date

Like `{{ date('Y-m-d', strtotime($invoice->invoice_created_date)) }}`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

```
{{date('Y-m-d',strtotime($invoice->invoice_created_date))}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the `invoice_created_date` to the `dates` model property and it will be mutated automatically to a `Carbon` object.

In the `Invoice` model add the dates property:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Invoice extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = [
        'invoice_created_date',
    ];
}
```

In the blade file you can simply format the date to whatever format you need:

```
{{ $invoice->invoice_created_date->format('Y-m-d') }}
```

You can [read more about date mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function

```
public static function dateChange($date)
        {
            $dt = explode(" ", $date);
            return $dt[0];
        }
```